# Visio Org Chart - Formatting and Numbers Coming Through

Tags: visio, orgchart

I am trying to create a visio org chart that looks like this:

[image]

However, this is all I can get so far:

[image]

1.) Does anyone know how to get rid of the picture? 
2.) Does anyone know how to add in organization abbrev boxes into my org chart, and color them, if necessary? 
3.) Does anyone know how to format the text on the boxes so I can have it show up as "POSITION GRADE – LAST NAME, POSITION TITLE" instead of the default list (which is what I have right now)? 
4.) Does anyone know why the ID number is only showing up as 0?

Thank you so much!!!!

Files here:
Excel:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XewYNXP6JqXVlQQ0kuaLTxK1efZTqm4c/view?usp=sharing

Visio:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nSKhCmAVWz8qvtv79-3PuY8SJT58jnzC/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Item 1: Select all the shapes then on the **Org Chart** ribbon click **Picture** -> **Delete**.